# Bernoulli trials with at least 1 success and 1 failure

Tags: probability-distributions

Independent Bernoulli trials are performed, with probability $1/2$ of success, until there has been at least one success. Find the PMF of the number of trials performed.

How is this different from the negative binomial?

Comment: $k$ trials happen iff there are $k-1$ failures then $1$ success, i.e. $P(k \text{ trials}) = \frac{1}{2^k}$

Comment: It is the geometric, a special case of the negative binomial.

Answer (score 1):

This is the *geometric* distribution, # of trials needed to get *first* success

**$P(x=k) = (1-p)^{k-1}\cdot p$**

The negative binomial distribution gives the # of trials needed to get *k* successes

So, as has been commented, the geometric distribution is a special case of the negative binomial distribution.

*Note*

Some count the # of *failures* for the negative binomial, but as you must be knowing, what is defined as "success" is just a matter of convenience.

Answer (score 0):

First we need to observe that the range of $X$ is $\{2, 3, 4, \dots\}$.
So for each integer $k \geq 2$, we get

$$ 
\{X = k\} \;=\; [S_1 \cap S_2 \cap S_3 ... \cap S_{k-1} \cap S^c_k] \;\cup\; [S^c_1 \cap S^c_2 \cap S^c_3 ... \cap S^c_{k-1} \cap S_k].
$$

So, we have, 
$$
\mathbb{P}(X = k) \;=\; \mathbb{P}(S_1 \cap S_2 \cap S_3 ... \cap S_{k-1} \cap S^c_k) \;+\; \mathbb{P}(S^c_1 \cap S^c_2 \cap S^c_3 ... \cap S^c_{k-1} \cap S_k)
$$
$$= \; p^{k-1}(1-p) + (1-p)^{k-1}p.$$