# Clarifying a question on the number of Bernoulli trials

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, bernoulli-distribution, geometric-distribution

The following question is from Blitztein-Hwang, Introduction to Probability:

*Independent Bernoulli trials are performed, with probability 1/2 of success, until
there has been at least one success. Find the PMF of the number of trials performed.*

Let $X$ be the number of trials performed.

When I first attempted the question, I concluded that $P(X=k) = 1-(\frac{1}{2})^k$ via the principle of inclusion-exclusion and the independence of events. My thought process here was the following: because the question says *until there has been at least one success*, then for $k$ trials, we need at least one success, i.e., we can get up to $k$ success.

Then, after a quick search, I stumbled on this previous question: [Bernoulli trials with at least 1 success and 1 failure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1353412/bernoulli-trials-with-at-least-1-success-and-1-failure). In the answer, it is stated that $X$ has a geometric distribution, i.e., $P(X=k) = (1-\frac{1}{2})^{k-1}\cdot \frac{1}{2} = (\frac{1}{2})^k$, but this assumes that after $k$ trials, we only have one success, so it seems more close to *until there has been a success* and not *until there has been at least one success*

Please, can someone help me understand which case better reflects the question and why?

Comment: This is not clear.  What is $X$?  The first success?  But that doesn't make sense...you have $P(X=k)\to 1 $ for large $k$.  If nothing else, we would have to have $\sum_k P(X=k)=1$.  Your sum diverges.

Comment: $X$ is the random variable that keeps track of the number of trials performed

Comment: That's not a variable.  You mean the number of trials it takes until you observe the first success?  Something else?

Comment: Based on what the problem said, I will say that it is the number of trials it takes until I observe at least one success...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is in this line:

> My thought process here was the following: because the question says until there has been at least one success, then for k trials, we need at least one success, i.e., we can get up to k success.

The key detail is that you're counting **until** the first success. This doesn't mean you can have up to $k$ successes; it means instead that your first $k-1$ trials could not have had a success, but that your $k^{\text{th}}$ one did, making it the first of them. That's the role of the word **until** in this context; it implies that we stop when we find a success. (Yes, the use of "at least one" becomes necessarily strange in this formulation.)

Comment: Thank you very much. This clears my uncomprehension